# How can I monitor my Alibaba Cloud ECS Instances?

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have ECS Instances with multiple configurations, various Operating System & applications.

Is there any application/Alibaba cloud product which can monitor them as a batch without logging into the instances?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by using the Alibaba Cloud's "Cloud Monitor"

To install a CloudMonitor, follow these steps:

1. In the Alibaba Cloud Console, choose Products and Services >  > CloudMonitor.
2. In the left-side navigation pane, click Host Monitoring, and then select the name of the instance you want to monitor.
3. Click Install to monitor the operating system of the instance. Click Batch Install to monitor the instance OS, click Monitoring Chart to view basic parameters, and click Alarm Rules to set alarm rules.

You should be able to view enough information on the instances and their statuses. If you are looking for more information, we have to write our application with the customization